# Who is the manufacturer of this tilt and turn window handle?

Tags: windows, hardware

I have these tilt and turn windows that operate in 3 positions - 0 degrees (closed), 90 degrees (open towards the inside), and 180 degrees (window tilt inward). The handle does not close properly on one of the windows and I have been trying to find a replacement handle. I haven't been able to identify the manufacturer of the handle. The back of the handle has markings of "CA" and "SAE".

Handle that doesn't work
[image: The handle that does not work]

Handle that works
[image: Handle that works]

The handle seems to be manufactured by "CA" but I haven't been able to find out who it is.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Presuming that the handle came with the window, look at the window frame (and the space between the window panes) for the identity of the window manufacturer. They'd know.